# Angular 2. Плавный скрол к якорю. scrollspy

Tags: angular2

Добрый день! 
Подскажите пожалуйста как делается плавный скрол к якорю на странице и как можно реализовать скрол-спай по странице средствами средствами Angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть неплохая библиотека [ng2-smooth-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-smooth-scroll).

После установки (`npm install ng2-smooth-scroll`) импортируйте необходимые компоненты в модуль *module.ts*

```
import { SmoothScrollToDirective, SmoothScrollDirective } from "ng2SmoothScroll";
...
declarations[
   ...
   SmoothScrollToDirective,
   SmoothScrollDirective,
   ...
]
```

В Вашем шаблоне установите якорь:

```
<div #my-element></div>
```

Ну и кнопка:

```
<button scrollTo="my-element">Scroll to</button>
```

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ответ, а хеш добавиться к url? 
или это отдельно прописывается через routerLink + fragment ну и queryParams по требованию

Comment: либу давно использовал, но насколько помню, она без якоря идёт. Якорь пишется в href а тут элемент надо вставить `<div #my-element></div>`.

Comment: Добрый день,  у меня что то не получается прикрутить SmoothScroll к своему проекту я делаю так как вы указали и получаю ошибку 
Cannot read property 'callbackBefore' of undefined
мне необходимо прокрутить не страницу а блок на странице это может быть как то связанно?

Comment: @aknysh такое впечатление что вы или не установили  ng2-smooth-scroll (npm install ng2-smooth-scroll) или не определили директиву в главном модуле. Вы проинсталили пакет?

Comment: да я поставил  локально для проекта подключил в модуле только не в базовом а в том который использую  ибо он лениво грузится и что то не взлетает... и меня смущает то что webstorme не подсказывает ни чего про этот модуль...

Comment: в браузере файлы библиотеке есть... и он не может получить значение this.callbackBefore так как this не определен... но меня больше смущает откуда он его возьмет когда там простая функция? 
даже если и будет this это условие ни когда не сработает if (this.callbackBefore) 

 ибо там   function (element){} и this будет к функции относиться а не классу

Comment: 1. Попробуйте использовать её в самой компоненте, добавив в @Component поле `directives: [SmoothScrollToDirective,SmoothScrollDirective ]`

Comment: @aknysh Соответственно importнужно сделать в этой компоненте

Comment: @aknysh Стоп у Вас есть в темплейте ` <a callbackBefore="callbackBefore(element)">...` в а самой компоненте нет 
callbackBefore ?

Comment: я не понимаю зачем мне нужна эта функция я ее ни где не использую

Comment: @ Component поле directives: [SmoothScrollToDirective,SmoothScrollDirective ] 
так же нельзя делать в angular4

Comment: @aknysh ага, в доке не указано, что так  можно сделать, значит вы правы так нельзя сделать. Вы в темплейте указывали эту функцию  при вызове директивы?

Comment: @aknysh можно глянуть Ваш код где-нибудь?

Comment: я тут расположил своей тестовой проект для обучения так сказать..  https://github.com/alexKnysh/AngularTest

https://github.com/alexKnysh/AngularTest/blob/master/RxJs/src/app/app.module.ts
подключение в модуле 
и использование 
https://github.com/alexKnysh/AngularTest/blob/master/RxJs/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: к сожалению у меня не получилось сделать плавный скрол. Скажите пожалуйста можно взглянуть на рабочий пример использования этой библиотеке?

Comment: нашел готовый пример только другой библиотеке...  https://nolanus.github.io/ng2-page-scroll/simple#head7

Comment: @aknysh у меня рабочего примера нет. В либе ошибка, потому что не получиться достучаться к this в setTimeout

Comment: я исправил эту ошибку заменив на стрелочные функции но все равно нет скрола...